# Is there a way to estimate how much space will be consumed by archivelogs?

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration

We are trying to get a grasp of the space requirements of switching from a backup process based on datapumps, to one based on RMAN and archivelogs. Currently we're a bit limited by space constraints, even though the database is about 20GB give or take, if you include temporary tablespaces, etc. I need to know how to estimate how large my archivelogs will become if I switch over to using them so I can tell our sysadmins how much space they need to give me (due to the backup measures they take on the server side, space increases take up exponentially amounts of additional space on the tape drives, so they get irritatingly stingy about it.

Answer (score 0):

Space consumed by archivelogs mostly depends upon the type of transactions happening on your database. If transactions are mostly select queries, you won't need that much space for archive storage as the generation frequency will be low.

If the database transactions are mostly dml or write based queries, you will need a larger storage area for archives as the frequency of generation will be high.

This also depends on how frequent checkpoints occur in the database and the size of your undo segments.

Since you have space constraints, I would suggest having a decent amount of space for archives and have frequent tape backups of the archivelogs so that backed up archives can be deleted from the server storage to gain space for newer archives.